# How to extract numbering and text from .docx file

Tags: java, apache-poi, extract, docx

How do I extract numbering and text from a `.docx` file using Java and the Apache POI XWPF library?

I am using the following code:

```
public static void readDocxFile() {

    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\test.docx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);
        List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();

        for (XWPFParagraph para : paragraphs) {
            System.out.println(para.getText());

            fis.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My code is only extracting the text, like below:

```
CLIENT SERVICE SATISFACTION
Client Feedback System
Interlibrary Loans
Shelf Tidiness
Three Day Loans
Materials Availability Survey
Online help service
```

I need to extract the chapter number (numbering) with the text, like the following:

```
1    CLIENT SERVICE SATISFACTION
1.1   Client Feedback System
1.1.1 Interlibrary Loans
1.1.2 Shelf Tidiness
1.1.3 Three Day Loans
1.2   Materials Availability Survey
1.3   Online help service
```

Comment: its only extracting `CLIENT SERVICE SATISFACTION,Client Feedback System,Interlibrary Loans`

Comment: That seems like useful information to include in the question. Also why are you closing `fis` while iterating over `paragraphs`, it may not cause an error but it is redundant. You should close `fis` outside of the loop.

Comment: yes i correct it but  sill  i couldn't extract  all values

Comment: I created a `.docx` with the numbering and text that you gave, downloaded Apache POI, then used your code, and I received the output that you want. I'm not sure why you're not getting the right output. Could you copy and paste the exact contents of the `.docx` that you're trying to extract from (not the whole document, just the numbering part).

Comment: can i send my sample document to you

Comment: Can you upload it somewhere and add the download link to your question?

Comment: [link](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjk1PC1icrNAhUNTI8KHdd6BE0QFgg3MAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.csus.edu%2Fgradstudies%2Fforms%2Ftemplates%2Fsectionbreaks.doc&usg=AFQjCNGRJ7PmPux5YjinRrhiMbEpw0WZhw&sig2=81T9Cii3VGJ3qg75rzlvPQ)  hear is the sample link please download using this link and save it as a **docx** file

Comment: @JonnyHenly  can you help me

Answer (score 0):

To get the text of a doc file, you need to use the XWFParagraph(use poi-ooxml API) method. To get the numbering of that paragraph try out the following code:

```
BigInteger currentParagraphNumberingID = currentPara_Line.getCTP().getPPr().getNumPr().getNumId().getVal(); 
BigInteger currentParagraphAbstractNumID2 = currentPara_Line.getDocument().getNumbering().getAbstractNumID(currentParagraphNumberingID);
XWPFAbstractNum currentParagraphAbstractNum = currentPara_Line.getDocument().getNumbering().getAbstractNum(currentParagraphAbstractNumID2); 
CTAbstractNum currentParagraphAbstractNumFormatting = currentParagraphAbstractNum.getCTAbstractNum();
```